# NGINX `limit_req` not working in location directive for an index file

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to add an nginx location directive for `limit_req`, but it's not working for me.

I have 2 targets where I wanted to add the `limit_req`.

Website
API path
Here is my server config file.

```
server {
    server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot

        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
                root /var/www/;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

location /example.com/{
                limit_req zone=mylimit;
                root /var/www/example.com/;
                index index.php?$args;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /example.com/index.php?$args;
        }
location /example.com/api/ {
                limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20 nodelay;
                root /var/www/example.com/api/;
                index index.php?$args;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /example.com/api/index.php?$args;
        }
}
```

When I try testing the above setting by parallel hitting the website login URL, the limit_req works. But, when I run the same test for API then it won't work.

All my APIs hit `https://example.com/api/index.php` URL. Can anyone help?

I am using seige for testing purposes.

```
siege -b -r 1 -c 10 https://example.com/api/index.php
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `limit_req` work in `location` for *.php files?